# Nginx setting server gives installation page

Tags: nginx, configuration, server-setup

I'm trying to set up Nginx for the first time and in following a tutorial I have come to the point that I'm getting the Welcome page to Nginx. I removed the last two includes in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and added the following code. However, no matter how many times I attempt to move things around I get only the welcome page and not the page in my htdocs directory.

I'm sure that I'm missing something simple, but any pointers would be appreciated.

```
server {
                listen          80;
                server_name     domain.com;
                root            /var/www/domain.com/htdocs;
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        try_files $uri =404;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        index index.html index.php;
                }
        }
```

Comment: are there other files in your '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/' folder?  they could be overriding your server entry.

Comment: I checked the file and commented out the items listed in it and restarted nginx. Still the same issue. I did stop the server and I noticed that I was still getting the site which seemed odd after 'service nginx stop'. To make sure that it was working I tried typing 'nginx' and it started. When I repeated this while it was running I would get the socket in use and stopping I wouldn't get that. So I was sure that the service was stopped. I also went into private mode in Chrome as well as Safari and same thing with the intro page.

Comment: Before location ~ \.php have one more block for location / with same content as you have for .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments it sounds like you are running two copies of nginx. Here's how you can troubleshoot:

```
service nginx stop
ps auxwww|grep nginx  # is it still running?
```

Once you have successfully stopped nginx, try checking locally using `curl` instead of using Chrome or Safari. This will bypass any caches/proxies and give you a better low level insight into what's going on. Let's say the public IP of your server is 1.2.3.4. Then on the same server running nginx you'd do something like this and check the output:

```
curl -XGET http://1.2.3.4:80
curl -XGET http://1.2.3.4:80/test.html
```

Now you have some data and you can do some deductions.

#### Case A

You still get the nginx welcome page even that you stopped the service and killed any lingering processes by hand. You're likely working on the wrong server or the IP isn't routing the way you expect. Maybe it's connected to a CDN like CloudFlare which shows the last retrieved page even when the server is down.

Try accessing the page through localhost to confirm:

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:80
```

#### Case B

You had to kill nginx by hand, but once you did the server did stop responding. In this case something is wrong with your service definition of nginx or something is starting it in a different way (supervisord, manual rc.local thing). The wrong settings files might be used as well.

Figure out what's starting nginx and get rid of it, then use your package manager to reinstall nginx with normal startup scripts.

#### Case C

Stopping the service did work, curl did not get a response after you did. In this case your testing with Chrome/Safari was likely affected by some caching or local proxy.

Start the service again and now use curl to test with until you get the configuration file right.